# What does the Promote menu option do?

Tags: azure-artifacts

Just noticed the Promote menu option on the package page.  It appears left of the Unlist option.  I cannot find any documentation on what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Promote adds a package to a *release view*, a filtered subset of the packages in the feed. Release views can help you communicate which packages are tested and ready to go. Check out the [docs here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/views).